# Appending Image Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having 3 images on top of my webpage, named img1,img2,img3.(Table1)

Also I am having 4 images on bottom of my page, named f1,f2,f3,f4.(Table2)

Now I am moving image f1 over the image img3, f2 over the img1, f3 over the img4.

I read the Table1 ids that displays but it shows the previous ids(img1,img2,img3), but I need to read as (f2,img2,f3)

```
<div >
<table id="t1" >
  <tr>
      <td id="td1" >
      <img id="img1" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/100/100/" draggable="false"/>
       </td>
    <td  id="td2"  >
      <img id="img2" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/h/100/100/" draggable="false"/>
       </td>
    <td id="td3" >
     <img id="img3" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/i/100/100/" draggable="false"/>
       </td>

     </tr>
</table>
</div>


<button id ="btnAnimate"   class="myButton">Done</button>

<button id ="btnGetID"   class="myButton"> Get ID</button>


<div style="padding-left:100px;padding-top:100px">
<table id="t2" >
  <tr>
      <td >
      <img id="f1" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/c/100/100/" draggable="false"/>
       </td>
    <td   >
      <img id="f2" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/l/100/100/" draggable="false"/>
       </td>
    <td  >
     <img id="f3" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/m/100/100/" draggable="false"/>
       </td>
    <td >
     <img id="f4" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/n/100/100/" draggable="false"/>
       </td>
     </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

JavaScript..

```
$("#btnGetID").on('click',function () {
       $('#t1 tr td').each(function(){
        alert($(this).find('img').attr('id'));
    });
});


$("#btnAnimate").click(function () {

 var v = $("#f1").offset();
  var p = $("#img3").offset();
 $("#f1").css({ "top": v.top + "px", "left": v.left + "px" , "position": "absolute"});

    $("#f1").animate({
        opacity: 1,
         top: p.top,
         left: p.left
    }, 1000);


 var v = $("#f2").offset();
 var p = $("#img1").offset();
 $("#f2").css({ "top": v.top + "px", "left": v.left + "px" , "position": "absolute"});

    $("#f2").animate({
        opacity: 1,
         top: p.top,
         left: p.left
    }, 1000);

var v = $("#f3").offset();
var p = $("#img4").offset();
 $("#f3").css({ "top": v.top + "px", "left": v.left + "px" , "position": "abs
```

For better understanding, here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/a09bshb7/57/

Regards,
Arun

Comment: The images are still in the second table in the dom. You are just changing the css. You would have to actually move the dom node to acchieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you not appendig img into the table, you just change position of this image, so content of table is same. if you want to append img's into table, use somethig like this

```
var myNewImg = $("#my_new_img");
$("#some_elem .children1").html(myNewImg);
```

P.S. you can start function that changing table contetn in the moment then animation complete - read jquery documentation